# Differential equation: $A(x)y''(x)+A'(x)y'(x)+y(x)/A(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

So give the differential equation

$$A(x)y''(x)+A'(x)y'(x)+\frac{y(x)}{A(x)}=0,$$
with $A(x)$ a *known* function and $y(x)$ te be determined. What is the solution for this differential equation ?

I've tried substituting $y(x)=A(x)u(x)$, but unfortunately this didn't eliminate my unknown variable $A(x)$. I don't know if there are any other tricks or substitutions that I can try to solve this situation ?

I als considered switching to $u=A(x)$ as my independent variable, but that also didn't help me that much ...

Comment: Crosslinked question with Mathematica code, now closed as a duplicate.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777867/known-but-not-given-non-constant-coefficients-in-a-second-order-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rearrange the equation to yield
$$
A^2y'' + AA'y' + y = 0 = A^2y'' + \left(\frac{A^2}{2}\right)'y' +  y
$$
mutiply by $y'$ we find
$$
A^2y''y' + \left(\frac{A^2}{2}\right)'y'^2 +  yy' = 0\\
\frac{A^2}{2}\left(y'^2\right)' + \left(\frac{A^2}{2}\right)'y'^2 +  yy' = 0
$$
the last equation can be written as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(A^2y'^2\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(y^2\right)' = 0
$$
or
$$
\left(A^2y'^2\right) + y^2 = \lambda
$$
so
$$
y' = \frac{\pm\sqrt{\lambda-y^2}}{A}
$$
or
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda-y^2}} dy = \pm\int \frac{1}{A}dx
$$

Comment: Very nice solution, I will check this one first thing in the moring! Do you have any tips on to see how this substitution becomes obvious ?

Comment: It only became obvious after I multiplyby the denominator of y. Since I saw that I could potential use the product rule but I was missing a half factor and even then I would have an integral for y with respect to x which is unhelpful, so mutiple by $y'$ did the trick to reduce the order.