# known (but not given) non-constant coefficients in a second order equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem and I am really unsure how to approach it (besides a first potential step). Here is the problem:

$$A(x)y''(x) + A'(x)y'(x) + \frac{y}{A(x)} = 0 $$

Where y(x) is unknown and A(x) is known, but not given. Looking for the general solution. My initial approach was to rewrite it as the following:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}[y'(x)A(x)] + \frac{y}{A(x)} = 0 $$

But I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @kipf this should be flagged as a duplicate question, then closed.  Thanks to kipf for finding it.

Comment: @kipf it certainly does. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One tries to get rid of the first derivative

```
    Coefficient[Numerator@ Together[
       A[x]^-1 D[A[x] y'[x], x] + y[x]/A[x]^2 /. {y -> (f[#] z[#] &)}],
          z'[x]]

    DSolve[ A[x] f[x]  A'[x] + 2 A[x]^2  f'[x],f[x],x]

     {{f[x] -> C[1]/Sqrt[A[x]]}}
```

The substitution yields a compact linear equation of second order

```
      0==Numerator@Together[
     A[x]^-1 D[A[x] y'[x], x] + y[x]/ A[x]^2 /. 
           {y -> ( z[#]/Sqrt[A[#]] &)}] // FullSimplify

     0 == z[x] (4 + A'[x]^2 - 2 A[x] A'' [x]) + 4 A[x]^2 (z'')[x]
```

So one needs the general solution of

```
      z'' + g[x] z == 0
```

or as the solution  of the system of first order

or

```
    {z,w}= {{0,1},{-g[x],0}} . {z,w}
```

Comment: This appears to be Mathematica code.  Is that correct?
I have no idea what you're suggesting the solution is.

Comment: Yes, since LaTeX over net is error prone for such substitions, I prefer to use the exact expressions formulated in Mathematica. The equation is the typical second order equation arising in separation of the Schrödinger eigenvualue equation  in separable coordinates $$-1/h^2 d/dx (h^2 f'(x) ) + 1/h^2 f(x) = m^2 f(x) =0$$ for the kernel m=0 or better Dirac $H f = delta(x)$  to find the Greens function as a distribution.